# How to write to a new text file and preserve white spacing?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to "spell check" a given text file, my program reads through the given file and refers to a dictionary hashset given by my teacher. If it finds a word that is not in the dictionary or is split by some characters, it surrounds the word with <>. One condition is that I need to preserve the white spaces between the words, and I do not know how to make sure the program does that.

current code:

```
public static void spellCheck(File processingFile, File dictionaryFile) {
        try {
            HashSet<String> dictionary = new HashSet<>();
            FileReader processing = new FileReader(processingFile);
            FileReader dictionaryF = new FileReader(dictionaryFile);
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("test_spellChecked.txt");
            
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(dictionaryF);
            String word = scnr.nextLine();
            while(scnr.hasNext()) {
                //dont need to check for double words cus its literally a dictionary
                dictionary.add(word);
                word = scnr.nextLine();
                
            }
            //somehow create a stored text file of the processing text that gets changed based on the dictionary check
            
            scnr = new Scanner(processing);
            word = scnr.next();
            boolean isCorrect = true;
            while(scnr.hasNext()) {
                if(word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                    if(!dictionary.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                        outputFile.print("<" + word + ">");
                    }
                    else
                        outputFile.print(word);
                }
                else {
                    String[] words = word.split("((?=[^a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))");
                    for(String splitWord: words) {
                        if(!dictionary.contains(splitWord.toLowerCase())) {
                            outputFile.print("<" + splitWord + ">");
                        }
                        else
                            outputFile.print(splitWord);
                    }
                }
                word = scnr.next();
            }
            
            outputFile.close();
            System.out.println("File has been checked.");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
        

    }
```

I just figured out how to rewrite the file with the same exact words into the file, I am not sure how to preserve the whitespaces.

Comment: To preserve whitespace, don't remove it in the first place. It is not removed from a String unless you, the coder, explicitly remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
            while(scnr.hasNext()) {
                if(word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                    if(!dictionary.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                        outputFile.print("<" + word + ">");
                    }
                    else
                        outputFile.print(word);
                }
                else {
                    String[] words = word.split("((?=[^a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))");
                    for(String splitWord: words) {
                        if(!dictionary.contains(splitWord.toLowerCase())) {
                            outputFile.print("<" + splitWord + ">");
                        }
                        else
                            outputFile.print(splitWord);
                    }
                }
                word = scnr.next();
            }
```

this is why space is deleted.

word and splitWord is not contain space.

because you are reading word with `scnr.next()`

`next()` reads file until space or line change.

change like this
`outputFile.print(splitWord+" ");` or
`outputFile.format("%s ", splitWord);`

will save space.

but this will not save `\n` or `\t`

if you want to save `\n` also,

```
      for(String word:words){
        if(word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
          if(!dictionary.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
            outputFile.print("<" + word + ">");
          }
          else
            outputFile.print(word);
        }
        else {
          String[] words = word.split("((?=[^a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))");
          for(String splitWord: words) {
            if(!dictionary.contains(splitWord.toLowerCase())) {
              outputFile.print("<" + splitWord + ">");
            }
            else
              outputFile.print(splitWord);
          }
        }
        outputFile.println();
      }
      nextLine = scnr.nextLine();
      words = nextLine.split(" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
word = scnr.next();
```

That causes the Scanner to discard all whitespace up to the next token.

To preserve everything in the file, you cannot use the zero-argument hasNext() and next() methods.

Instead, use the [hasNext(Pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)) and [next(Pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)) methods, so you will be able to keep every character:

```
Pattern wordPattern = Patter.compile("(\\W*)(\\w+)");

while (scnr.hasNext(wordPattern)) {
    scnr.next(wordPattern);

    String separator = scnr.match().group(1);
    String word = scnr.match().group(2);

    outputFile.print(separator);
    if (!dictionary.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
        outputFile.print("<" + word + ">");
    } else {
        outputFile.print(word);
    }
}
```